# Can I check changes already merged in to other branch before merge in master

Tags: git, github

Am setting up new a GitHub branching strategy. I have a `master` branch and a `QA` branch. Am going to create a `feature` branch from `master`, when I need to send my feature to test I will merge my changes to `QA` branch when it is ready to release I will merge to `master` from the `feature` branch.

Can I verify my `feature` branch is already merged to `QA` branch before merging to `master`?

I don't want to merge changes from `QA` to `master` because sometimes I don't want to release all my features which are in QA.

Is it Posible to restrict the merge to `master` without merging to `QA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git branch --contains feature
```

will output the list of branches where `feature` has already been merged. (or the reverse `--no-contains` if you prefer to check presence instead of absence, but the principle is the same) ([--contains](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---containsltcommitgt))

Another way could be to check if there are commits in `feature` which aren't yet reachable through `QA` ([two-dots range notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation))

```
git log --oneline QA..feature
```

will output nothing if your branch is already merged in `QA`. In the opposite case, you'll have the list of commits "to be merged in"

---

*(Both commands can be executed from any branch, no need to `checkout` anything beforehand. However, be sure to have recently `fetch`ed, or you might have obsolete references for branches which have been merged remotely)*

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working like a champ. But can I add this as a rule? before merging to `master` this condition should satisfy. Means everything should be merged to `QA` before merging to `master`?

Comment: @Venki What do you mean by "rule" here? Enforce it with a local hook?

Comment: am not sure about the `local hook`, am new to `GitHub`. Somehow I need to restrict the merge to `master` from `feature` before merging to `QA`.

Comment: So check [hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) for a local strategy, or consider enforcing a merge requests strategy (i.e. instead of merging locally, you push your feature branch to the repo and create a merge request there)

Comment: Yes we are doing that, we are pushing the feature branch to repo and creating a pull request. Can we add this restriction while merging or creating pull request?

Comment: @Venki Yes, people with the relevant rights on the repo can configure branches to refuse direct push, prompting the need to use pull requests for all changes to this branch. Furthermore, you can request validation from any number of coworkers to be able to merge pull requests targetting a given branch if needed.